# html-webpack-plugin does not inject css file

Tags: webpack, html-webpack-plugin

### Expected behaviour

When I use template file, I expected the output file has both injected js file and css file.

### Current behaviour

When I use template file, I found the output file has js file injected, but css file lost...
And when not use template, the output file is correct, both has js file and css file...

### Environment

OS: mac osx 10.15.4
Node.js v12.16.2
darwin 19.4.0
npm 6.14.4
webpack 4.43.0
html-webpack-plugin: 4.3.0

#### Config

```js
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const FriendlyWebpackPlugin = require("friendly-errors-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');


module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "cheap-source-map",
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: "index.[hash:8].js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "../dist"),
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    port: 8080,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: "html-loader",
      },
      // {
      //   test: /\.css$/i,
      //   use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      // },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              // publicPath: '../',
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            },
          },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              // you can specify a publicPath here
              // by default it uses publicPath in webpackOptions.output
              // publicPath: '../',
              hmr: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
          },
          {
            loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                javascriptEnabled: true,
                strictMath: true,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|png)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 10000,
          // name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'ENV': require('../config/dev.env')
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'index.[hash:8].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css'
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      title: 'admin',
      template: path.join(__dirname, "../src/index.html"),
      // chunks: ['index'],
      inject: true,
      // minify: {
      //   html5: true,
      //   collapseWhitespace: true,
      //   preserveLineBreaks: false,
      //   minifyCSS: true,
      //   minifyJS: true,
      //   removeComments: false,
      // },
    }),
    new FriendlyWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" /> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/iconfont/iconfont.css"/> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../src/css/video-react.css"/> -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="//at.alicdn.com/t/font_389542_wle9cc2fi7wrk9.css" /> -->
  <!--[if lte IE 10]>
      <script
        src="https://as.alipayobjects.com/g/component/??console-polyfill/0.2.2/index.js,media-match/2.0.2/media.match.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <!-- <script src="./index.js"></script> -->
  <!--<script src="../src/iconfont/JsonExportExcel.min.js"></script>-->
</body>

</html>
```

### Relevant Links & minimal reproduce

https://github.com/shauvet/code-reproduce/tree/webpack4-test

### Additional context

Add any other context about the problem here.
steps 1: yarn 
steps 2: yarn start

then check http://localhost:8080/#/login

Answer (score 1):

My fault, less file should also with MiniCssExtractPlugin...

And now css file has been into the html.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/ try import the css first

Comment: Do you mean I import css file in index.js? But actually the css file is generated by MiniCssExtractPlugin. So I dont know the file name...